# Remove shortcuts windows mobile

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I have an application developed  on Windows Mobile and Windows CE using C#. I need to disable keys native Windows shortcut on the device where my application is installed. 
I need that when my application is working the keys of native Windows shortcut does not work. For example F1, F2 ... . 
Because I want to use them these keys (wrapper) on the website that my application will open.
I need to do this for both Windows Mobile as Windows CE.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the hook system with DllImport, an example [here on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49881/Hooking-the-keyboard-message-queue-in-compact-fram.aspx)

> You can use this to catch the funny OS assigned keys like F1, F2, F3,
>   F4, F6 and F7 (Softkey 1 and 2, Phone, End, Volume Up, Volume Down);
>   and last but not least catch the Win Key press.

Comment: Ty u MathB.Fr. I'm trying to implement the example for my application. When i get results, I'll post here.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are ways to unlink the function keys of there Windows Mobile OS functions, this may possibly not work within the Internet Explorer Mobile (IEM) or a hosted webbrowser control.

The easiest way to get all keys into an application is to use the AllKeys(bool) API with the argument TRUE.

If you host a webbrowser control, you may so catch the function keys and send them directly into the webbrowser control window. But then it depends on the webbrowser rendering engine, if the function key values are issuing an javascript event. The new Windows Mobile (>6.1.5) engine supports javascript key events (see http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/27/windows-mobile-redirect-function-keys-into-internet-explorer-mobile-browser/ and http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/05/14/internet-explorer-mobile-handles-key-events/).

Some closed down kiosk mode browsers, like Intermec Browser and Naurtech TE, provide special setups to enable you to call javascript functions directly for functio (and other) keys.

On Windows CE devices there is normally no need for special function key handling as the OEMs do not use pre-defined function keys. But this depends on the OEM, every Windows CE OS can be designed freely. There is no standard as forced with Windows Mobile certification.

If you can avoid it, I would recommend to not use function key assignments in web browser applications.

If you need to process funcion keys in IEM6 you may need something like my iHookIE6 which redirects function keys directly into IEM: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/27/windows-mobile-redirect-function-keys-into-internet-explorer-mobile-browser/

Remember that key handling is part of the javascript engine on the client side.

Feel free to search my web site for more on function keys and Windows Mobile web browser engine.

Comment: Ty u Josep, I'll think about it. Because this is my scenario, my application works with the native Microsoft webbrowser.

Comment: Then I recommend you to use something like my iHookIE6: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/27/windows-mobile-redirect-function-keys-into-internet-explorer-mobile-browser/